# PostgreSQL - Difference in results between LIKE and '=' when using citext

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

On my DB, when querying

```
select my_field from my_table where my_field = 'ABC-123a'
```

it yields 0 results

but when querying

```
select my_field from my_table where my_field like 'ABC-123a'
```

it yields one result: `ABC-123a`

Am on a PostrgreSQL DB, and the field is a citext.

*EDIT : the encoding is `UTF8`*

I did some digging and found that `LIKE` compares character by character, while `=` compares whole strings.

In that case, I do not understand why using LIKE without any wildcard '%' would lead to these results.
As I understand it now, it means that all characters are equals, but the whole string isn't, and I don't get how that is possible?

I do not believe I have trailing spaces either (but I think that doesn't apply for Postgre anyway afaik)

I tried a bunch of queries to debug with ILIKE / TRIM / LENGTH to compare.
I looked for special unicode characters / blank spaces etc

But I still haven't found an explanation as to why the = doesn't return anything.

Comment: To your question add 1)What is the returned value for `my_field` in the `LIKE` case? 2) What encoding are you using?

Comment: Well it returns exactly `ABC-123a` (I can't share the real data for obvious reasons, but I made sure it's the exact same format and case sensitivity of 3 letters, a '-', and another letter.

As for the encoding, it's UTF8.
Updated the post accordingly.

Comment: 1) I should have been more specific, what does `SHOW lc_ctype` return? 2) What does `select my_field, char_length (my_field), octet_length(my_field) ...` return? 3) What about `select my_field from my_table where my_field::text like 'ABC-123a'`?

Answer (score 0):

Was fixed by running a `reindex index`

The `LIKE` doesn't use the index even without wildcards which explains the differences in results between using `=` and `LIKE`

The execution plans were not the same as one was using the - faulty (somehow) - index and the other was not